# How to sum hourly metrics into daily and monthly aggregates in Graphite & Grafana?

Tags: aggregate, grafana, graphite

Suppose a system collecting hourly energy consumptions (Wh) from clients with power analyzers (i.e. a sensor that measures how much energy an electrical appliance consumes).

In detail, each client periodically publishes the energy value consumed by a device in the last hour. On the server side, this data is stored in [Graphite](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) (v1.2.0) and visualized in a [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) (v6.5.2) dashboard.

In the dashboard, I can easily show hourly consumptions of a device as a line/bar graph. However, I need graphs to show total daily and monthly consumptions aggregating hourly values.

How can I do that using Graphite and/or Grafana without collecting extra metrics? Or is it at least possible or not?

Comment: how is the energy value metric being reported at each interval? is it a running "count" metric in that it increases forever, or does it reset after the report is made at each period?
for example a running count: t=1 v=10, t=2 v=20, t=3 v=30
or a reset count: t=1 v=10, t=2 v=10, t=3 v=10

If the latter, then a [summarize function](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) with the sum aggregation method to a daily/monthly period should work. or else you might want to use the max aggregation method and some other functions to make it work

Comment: Hey @tonyennis. It is the latter. So, we reset at each interval.

Comment: doing a summarize with sum aggregate function over 1d and 30d should do the job.